# Why this ruby syntax works in this example?

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
for i in (1..10).to_a do
  p "#{i} #{i[0]} #{i[1]}"
end
```

The result will be:

```
"1 1 0"
"2 0 1"
"3 1 1"
"4 0 0"
"5 1 0"
"6 0 1"
"7 1 1"
"8 0 0"
"9 1 0"
"10 0 1"
```

I thought that arr[i][i] returns 0 if the number is even but seems that here works some other logic

Comment: `i` traverses the numbers `1` through `10` and `i[0]` / `i[1]` returns the number’s _bit_ at position `0` / `1`. See [`Integer#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D)

Comment: There is no array syntax in your code. Can you be more specific about the precise problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

int[n] → 0, 1 => Returns the nth bit in the binary representation of int, where int[0] is the least significant bit.

```
      i[1] i[0]
0   0   0   1  => 1
0   0   1   0  => 2
0   0   1   1  => 3
0   1   0   0  => 4
0   1   0   1  => 5
0   1   1   0  => 6
0   1   1   1  => 7
1   0   0   0  => 8
1   0   0   1  => 9
1   0   1   0  => 10
```